# Can a woman marry more than one husband in Jannah?

Tags: nikah, women, jannah, husband

i am a girl and even if it sounds weird i have crush on many fictional men and i wanted to know when i go to jannah can i marry all of them? i know a woman can have only one husband in here but Jannah is the place of wonders you know.

Comment: Why do you want to marry more than one man ? Is it for Sex or for something else?